# Can i use Docker Desktop to manage a VPS running Docker?

Tags: docker, networking, vps, docker-desktop

I am very new to Docker as a whole.

I have a VPS with Debian 10 Buster, running Docker. I also installed Docker Desktop on my windows 10 pc. I like the GUI, and I googled if i can manage my VPS docker with this application, but found no answear.

Is this possible, or am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

While I have not been able to connect the Windows 10 Docker Desktop application to my Docker engine running on my Debian 10 VPS, I found an alternative:

[portainer.io](https://portainer.io)

This is a service, with a free plan option(CE). You install this docker image following their [documentation](https://documentation.portainer.io/), and it runs on the host machine, in my case, the Debian VPS. I use this image on port 9000, so all I have to do to access it is open a browser and navigate to http://HOSTIPADDRESS:9000.

There you will find a gui similar to the Docker Desktop application.